# Why do I get only a part of string when I use getString in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I saved a string in resources file, I run Code A and get Result A, I hope to get the Result B.

What's wrong with my code?

**Result A**

```
Recommend the app to a friend
```

**Code A**

```
   val context = LocalContext.current
   val temp=context.getString(R.string.myRecommendContent)


   <string name="myRecommendContent"><a href="#">Recommend</a> the app to a friend</string>
```

**Result B**

```
<a href="#">Recommend</a> the app to a friend
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this has been downvoted and all, but have you tried:

```
    <string name="myRecommendContent">&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;Recommend&lt;/a&gt; the app to a friend</string>
```

By what I can see, it ignores you're "other" elements such as the `anchor` element and just goes on with the `string` element itself.

Comment: Thanks! But your code can't be compiled

Comment: @HelloCW tell me the error, we might not be using the same compiler.

Comment: @HelloCW I've edited it now, I am determined to correctly answer your question no mater what.

Comment: @HelloCW I've edited it again to make sure that the double quotes are shown, also please tell me if it works this time or not.